# React native app sourcemaps show incorrect location of error when error happens in asynchronous code

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-sentry

I have a react-native app. I recently moved to react-native version `0.61.5` for which I took the long route of creating a new react-native app and porting my code over to avoid any linking issues since new version used PODFILE as the default linking mechanism. Ever since I moved to version `0.61.5`, I don't get the correct location of code in error logs. I think this is mainly happening when the code is running in asynchronous fashion which most of the code is. For e.g., look at below screenshot:

[image: Sample crash]

It is reporting that it is not able to call `map` on some array which is apparently `undefined` but the place where the error is reported is completely incorrect. I have no such file in my codebase and it is probably pointing to some file in some react-native package.

I am using Sentry `@sentry/react-native": "^1.1.0"`. I don't think Sentry can cause issue with the sourcemaps reported during development.

I am not sure how to debug this problem. This problem is causing a lot of issues in debugging any errors as I have to manually figure out where the error happened.  Please let me know if you have any tips on how to fix this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm not using sentry (I'm using bugsnag) and I'm also on 0.61.5

No idea how to tackle this.